# Should we keep new user's 'bad' and closed questions at 0?

Tags: discussion

**I have the feelng that this site..**

Doesn't have the number of users it should have yet; I think it's very very useful and one day there will be all kinds of publishers, tournamet pro players, casual gamers, poker rockstars..

**So I just read..**

[This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9316/was-planet-masters-a-good-concept-now-that-roll-for-the-galaxy-is-published) which was closed as it should, that's not to discuss.  But.. are the downvotes beneficial or harmful?

I am a afraid that this kind of welcome to a new user encourages them strongly to never interact again.  Isn't it enough to close the question?

In the long run it's much better to hear from him again, this time in the proper format

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the question.  I missed the first time around that the asker was the one who released the game.  Not disclosing that plainly is a violation of our FAQ.

One downvote comes as a consequence of the question being closed.  There isn't anything we can do about that.

This isn't a forum and we need to strike a balance between guiding new users to asking/answering questions the SE way and being welcoming.  I don't think we should lower our standards to attract new users.  There are plenty of forums out there for people to discuss boardgames.

If we keep doing what we do best, traffic will come.  We've tripled our traffic over the last year, traffic keeps going up.

Comment: The system automatically gives one dowvote when the question is closed?

Comment: @quinestor - yes, for some closure types.  Looking for a canonical reference.  I believe the -1 comes with everything except Duplicate and off topic closures.

Comment: @quinestor - my guess was wrong.  Details here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati